# Vim: corresponding colon command to "a" in normal mode

Tags: vim

As we know that you can't enter insert mode by

```
:exec "normal [iIaAs]"
```

The only way I know to enter the insert mode from colon command is

```
:startinsert[!]
```

While the :startinsert performs like 'i' and :startinsert! like 'A'. But how can I get 'a'?
You can't use

```
:exec "normal l"
:startinsert
```

because it doesn't work at the end of line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This snippet:

```
function! Append()
  startinsert
  normal! l
endfunction

nmap <F6> :call Append()<CR>
```

makes `<F6>` work like `a`.

Outside of a script, you must do:

```
:startinsert
<C-o>
:normal l
```

Note that `execute` is necessary only if you do some interpolation or concatenation in the command you want to execute.

```
execute "normal a"
```

is pointless but

```
execute "normal a" . my_variable
```

is correct.

Comment: I've tried the 'startinsert and normal! l' but the insert position can't get to the end of line.  I wander if there are some fix?

Comment: You should explain what you are trying to do (a script? commands for batch editing? something else?): a simple `:startinsert!` would obviously solve your "end of line" problem.

Comment: Parden my new to vimscript. But how can I determine whether the cursor's position is just behind the end of line (in script).

Comment: Compare `col(".")` with `col("$") - 1`. Some background info could help.

Answer (score 2):

does `feedkeys` function help ?

e.g.

```
:call feedkeys('a','n')
```

Comment: Now I use 'imap <C-f> <Esc>l:call feedkeys('a', 'n')<cr>'. If I type <C-f> at the end of line, vim exit the insert mode but not keep still. How can I fix it?

Comment: @RealYang why do you need that if you are already in insert mode? you can just press `right` or `C-O l`

Comment: Well I'm writing a script to auto-complete brackets and I want a fast way to skip a right bracket.  `C-O l` doesn't work if ")" is at end of line.  Furthermore, I think `C-O l` and `right` are slow.